# Yii2: How to log controller and action id for each request?

Tags: php, events, event-handling, yii2

I am trying to log every controller's actions by same code:

```
public function afterAction($action, $result)
{
    \Yii::$app->logger->write(0, $action->controller->id, $action->id);
    return parent::afterAction($action, $result);
}
```

But, I don't want redeclare this method on every controller, and I don't want to use some BaseController with same method. 
I know, base/Controller has AfterAction Event, but how to log controller actions, using his event handler ?

Comment: Why not simply using a log target ?? http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-logging.html

Comment: It will be looking like simple history of the actions of user. Logger is a simple component, which works with log AR model. Method write saves model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a [Class-Level Event Handler](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-events.html#class-level-event-handlers) in the [boostrap](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-applications.html#bootstrap) process like this (most likely in the web.php configuration file, which holds the [configuration for the application](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-configurations.html#application-configurations) object):

```
use yii\base\ActionEvent;
use yii\base\Controller;
use yii\base\Event;

$config = [
    ...
    'bootstrap'    => [
        ...
        function () {
            Event::on(Controller::class, Controller::EVENT_AFTER_ACTION, function (ActionEvent $event) {
                Yii::info('Called controller/action: ' . $event->action->id . '/' . $event->action->controller->id);
            });
        },
        ...
    ],
    ...
];
```